# Using CGAL, is it possible to perform Boolean operation on open polygon mesh?

Tags: c++, graphics, cgal

I have get to polygon mesh, namely `A` and `B`.

`A` is a closed mesh, `B` is an arbitrary surface. What I want to do is to cut off the part of `B` which located outside `A`. For example, if `A` is a polygon sphere and `B` is a rectangular plain, the result shall be a polygon circular plain.

I want to perform the above operation using CGAL (or may be other library if CGAL cannot do this). Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the "3D Boolean Operations on Nef Polyhedra" library:

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_3/index.html

Comment: I've studied that these days. However, it seems that CGAL Nef Polyhedra can only deal with closed geometry, while I a thin surfce to process. I have find a workround to avoid this boolean operation so I havn't study this problem further.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not correct.  Nef polyhedra do support non-manifold geometry: http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~kettner/proj/Nef/

Comment: Good news for me, thank you. I gain the idea "Nef is for manifold" form an official example which converts a Polygon to Nef Polyhedra. In the example, there is a statement "if(Polygon.isclosed()) ..." and I thus thought Nef Polyhedra only works for manifold.

Answer (score 1):

Regular boolean operations are useless here, e.g.
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::**corefine_and_compute_intersection**(mesh1, mesh2, meshout)
**requires** both mesh1 and mesh2 to be a **closed** meshes bounding some **volumes**.

For **open mesh** use:

CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::**clip**()

Say, mesh1 is open mesh (e.g. **square**) and mesh2 bounds some volume (e.g. **sphere**), then you can get **intersection** of mesh1 and mesh2 by calling:

```
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::clip(mesh1, mesh2);
```

The result (a **circle**) will be saved into mesh1.

If you need **difference** operation instead (**square with circle hole**), the same **clip**() may help either. In this case you need to reverse mesh2 first by swapping orientation of each triangle in mesh2 from counter-clockwise to clockwise. To reverse mesh orientation use:

```
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::reverse_face_orientations(mesh2);
```